# Auto Filter a sheet list and delete marked sheets and create new updated sheet from a sample sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking a shot at VBA for the first time so hoping someone can help. I have a large model with lots of sheets which are from a template sample worksheet and with  value set to the serial number of the sheet on each one and the name of the worksheet set to  on the master sheet list.

The master sheet list has three columns

Sheet Number--Sheet Name--Delete Flag

1-- Baby_24-- Yes

2-- Baby_36-- No

3-- Baby_48-- No

4-- Baby_60-- Yes

Trying to write a macro that goes through the master sheet list (Columns A through C), filters for Delete Flag "Yes", deletes all the sheets in the filtered dataset.

After it does that then it should go through the same list and recreate the sheets again by copying the  sheet and renaming to  in the master list and updating cell value B$2$ on that sheet to the sheet number in the master list. This is what I have so far.

The code generates a debug error and deletes only the first filtered sheet market "Yes" in the set and never goes to the next sheet.

```
Sub DeleteSheets()
' Delete Sheets Marked as Yes on SkuGroup Worksheet

    Dim rRange As Range, filRange As Range, Rng As Range
    ' Turn off Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Set your range
    Set rRange = Sheets("SKU_Groups").Range("A1:C999")

    With rRange
        '~~> Set your criteria and filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=Yes"

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
        Set filRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

        Debug.Print filRange.Address

        For Each Rng In filRange
            '~~> Your Code
            ActiveCell.Value2 = Range("B" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
            Sheets(ActiveCell.Value2).Delete
            Next
    End With

    'Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Turn on Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: which line throws which error?

Comment: What error and on which line?

Comment: Sheets(ActiveCell.Value2).Delete throws the error (Subscript out of range)

Answer (score 0):

No need to filter . try this :

```
Sub DeleteSelectedSheets()
    Dim masterSheetName
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    masterSheetName = "master"
    Sheets(masterSheetName).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim rowNum
    rowNum = 1
    Do Until Cells(rowNum, "B").Value = ""
        If Cells(rowNum, "C").Value = "Yes" Then
            For Each sh In Worksheets
                If sh.Name = Cells(rowNum, "B").Value Then
                    sh.Delete
                    Rows(rowNum).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    rowNum = rowNum - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```